# Datagrid + Map column to struct fields

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I'm trying to bind a datagrid (WPF C# 4.0 with WPF Toolkit) to the fields of a structure.  I basically have a datagrid with two columns.  The first I would like to be labels, the second I would like to be the members of a structure.  Perferably I would like to treat the series of rows as a single structure which can then be used elsewhere in my program.

Currently I have the program adding new instances of some class for each row, but I would prefer to treat it all as one... is there a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ViewModel

```
/// <summary>
/// DataGridRowViewModel
/// </summary>
public class DataGridRowViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// structureField
    /// </summary>
    private string structureField;

    private string lableText;

    /// <summary>
    /// StructureField        
    /// </summary>
    public string StructureField
    {
        get { return structureField; }
        set
        {
            structureField= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StructureField");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// StructureField        
    /// </summary>
    public string LableText
    {
        get { return lableText; }
        set
        {
            lableText= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LableText");
        }
    }

}



/// <summary>
/// DataGridRowViewModel
/// </summary>
public class MainViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// structureField
    /// </summary>
    private ObservableCollection<DataGridRowViewModel> rowCollection; 
    //Make Property with INotifyPropertyChanged

    /// <summary>
    ///   Default Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
          RowCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataGridRowViewModel>();
          FillCollectionWithStructureFields();
    }

    private void FillCollectionWithStructureFields()
    {
          //Fill Add New Instances of DataGridRowViewModel with required Label  
          // and Structure Filead Values
    }
}
```

## View

Bind the collection to DataGrid with required Columns...